# Using Fiddler with Google Chrome

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, fiddler

I am using Fiddler 2 debugging tool with IE and Firefox. Now I am trying to analyse the Http Requests using fiddler in google chrome. But there is no possible way to get start with fiddler in Chrome, as there is no icons or entry point is available in chrome. Can anyone tell me how to use fiddler with chrome.

Comment: just start your Fiddler2 from your start menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. As Google chrome is using Internet explorers proxy settings. I can start it in either from start menu or from the IE tools->fiddler2. And the traffic can be analysed.. Thanks Kris..

Answer (score 5):

If you have "FoxyProxy" or "SwitchySharp" extensions installed, try disabling them. They interfere with fiddler.

Comment: Yes, VPN extensions are issue creator for me.